# android writing license keys

Tags: android

I want to publish an application on Android Market.
I wan't the application to be free for trial period, which after it will stop working unless the user purchases a license / unlock key.
I saw on Android Market that many applications use such mechanism.

1. How do I write application that a user can purchase but is only a license key (not listed in app drawer, and basically does not have any functionality other than being installed)?
2. How do know the actual time that passed since application was installed without having to worry that the user may have uninstalled / reinstalled, wiped data etc?

thanks